# Gradle not downloading the right version of a component

Tags: kotlin, gradle, vaadin

I am working on a Kotlin project that uses Vaadin framework.

I am trying to migrate my project from Vaadin 22 to Vaadin 23.3.

I have encountered lots of issues, but one of them is "Gradle downloading the wrong version of a Vaadin component."

The Vaadin component is called Enhanced Dialog, from Vaadin Component Factory.

I changed the ENHANCED_DIALOG constant in my **Versions.kt** from 21.0.0 to 23.1.2 since the former is not compatible with Vaadin 23.

When I check the downloaded Gradle files, I find the following in **EnhancedDialog.java** :

```
@NpmPackage(value = "@vaadin-component-factory/vcf-enhanced-dialog", version = "21.0.0")
```

Any ideas about this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your gradel build file

Comment: Yes of course. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Is1dnkvgHKdG_g8Lw0whFzxTICXEiytU/view?usp=sharing
This is the main build.gradle file in the project folder. There are several other build.gradle files in the sub-folders of the project.
Also, this is the project I am working on: https://github.com/kopiLeft/Galite. (You can find all the build.gradle files in here, but not synched to what I have locally). This public version is using Vaadin 22. The one I have locally is attempting to use Vaadin 23.3.

Comment: And what are the constants of Versions

Comment: There are many constants obviously, but compared to the one on Github, I have the following three changed: const val VAADIN = "23.3.0", const val KARIBU_TESTING = "1.3.23", const val ENHANCED_DIALOG = "23.1.2".

Comment: Just noting, that when using Vaadin 23.3 you do not need Enhanced Dialog anymore, the features provided by the add-on were included into normal Dialog component, i.e. the header and footer sections.

Comment: @TatuLund: Oh, I did not know that. Thanks for the information. How could I know what has changed between Vaadin 22 and Vaadin 23.3? I checked this URL but it does not have enough information. https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-23-is-finally-here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by setting

```
@NpmPackage(value = "@vaadin-component-factory/vcf-enhanced-dialog", version = "23.0.0")
```

in a file that inherits from Vaadin's `EnhancedDialog.java`.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Your problem is that the version of the Enhanced Dialog dependency in the Gradle file is not correct. Note the version of the add-on is not automatically determined from Vaadin version. The add-on version needs to be defined separately.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it is theoretically correct or not, but my Gradle is bringing the correct version now. I want to mention that I changed it in two spots.
A first time, the constant `ENHANCED_DIALOG = "23.0.0"` in my `Versions.kt` file that my build.gradle bring versions from.
A second time, by changing that line in the file that inherits from Vaadin's `EnhancedDialog.java.`

Comment: Just noting, that dependencies with `@NpmPackage` are installed with npm during build, not with Gradle or Maven.